# WPF set old style for radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, radio-button

So, may be its so stupid question, but I need same radio button as this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

But when I wrote in XAML-file:

```
<ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtnInkMode" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="drawMode">Ink Mode!</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtnEraseMode" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="drawMode">Erase Mode!</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="rbtnSelectMode" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="drawMode">Select Mode!</RadioButton>
</ToolBar>
```

I got not expecting result:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Of course its looks better, but I expected and want get old radio buttons as in WinForms!
I work in Visual Studio 2015 Community in C# - WPF project. 
If somebody knows how return "old style" of radio buttons by easy way (understandable for XAML-beginner) write answer on this the question as soon as possible!

Comment: Can you give the context of your Xaml because I used your xaml and I've got the expected [result](http://imgur.com/a/L2yh9)

Comment: Your radiobuttons appear to be inside a toolbar, and the toolbar is overriding the default style.

Comment: @NemoUA Please add full xaml code to question. It's not clear from the current part from where this behavior could appear

Comment: @RogerN yes, i used toolBar. I got example, and there this radio buttons put in Tool box. So I want to do it as in example.

Comment: @Cedric [XAML file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39dXitRbPJVX0hlR3g2Z2hsQU0/view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the WPF ToolBar template apply a style to radio buttons:

`"{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.RadioButtonStyleKey}}"`

Try specify the style like that:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type RadioButton}}" x:Name="rbtnInkMode" GroupName="drawMode">Ink Mode!</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type RadioButton}}" x:Name="rbtnEraseMode" GroupName="drawMode">Erase Mode!</RadioButton>
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type RadioButton}}" x:Name="rbtnSelectMode" GroupName="drawMode">Select Mode!</RadioButton>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!